# Wrapping 32 bit libraries with f2py/gfortran on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, macos, gcc, enthought, f2py

I need to wrap a Fortran library in Python, and it needs to be 32 bit since I'm using the 32 bit EPD.  To do that I'm using f2py that ships with EPD and gcc 4.8 that I installed from fink.  I issue the following command:

```
f2py -c -m libplot3d --fcompiler=gnu95 plot3d.f90
```

The output is at the bottom.  Note the "file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)" warning at the end.  So what am I doing wrong, and how do I address this issue?

```
f2py -c -m libplot3d --fcompiler=gnu95 plot3d.f90
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "libplot3d" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.c
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'plot3d.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
    Block: libplot3d
            Block: open_file
            Block: close_file
            Block: read_nblk
            Block: read_header
            Block: read_param
            Block: read_one_block
            Block: write_nblk
            Block: write_header
            Block: write_param
            Block: write_one_block
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "libplot3d"...
        Constructing wrapper function "open_file"...
          open_file(file_name,endian)
        Constructing wrapper function "close_file"...
          close_file()
        Constructing wrapper function "read_nblk"...
          nblk = read_nblk()
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "read_header"("read_header")...
        Constructing wrapper function "read_header"...
          read_header(jkmmax,nblk)
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "read_param"("read_param")...
        Constructing wrapper function "read_param"...
          read_param(jmax,p)
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "read_one_block"("read_one_block")...
        Constructing wrapper function "read_one_block"...
          read_one_block(jkmmax,ndi,b)
        Constructing wrapper function "write_nblk"...
          write_nblk(nblk)
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "write_header"("write_header")...
        Constructing wrapper function "write_header"...
          write_header(jkmmax,nblk)
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "write_param"("write_param")...
        Constructing wrapper function "write_param"...
          write_param(jmax,p)
        Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "write_one_block"("write_one_block")...
        Constructing wrapper function "write_one_block"...
          write_one_block(jkmmax,ndi,b)
    Wrote C/API module "libplot3d" to file "/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.c"
    Fortran 77 wrappers are saved to "/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3d-f2pywrappers.f"
  adding '/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding '/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7
copying /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7
  adding '/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3d-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /sw/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'libplot3d' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386

creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo
creating /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7
compile options: '-I/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc: /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.c
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15,
                 from /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.c:2:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
gcc: /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.c
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15,
                 from /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.c:18:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: /sw/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: /sw/bin/gfortran -Wall -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: /sw/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-I/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c'
gfortran:f90: plot3d.f90
gfortran:f77: /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3d-f2pywrappers.f
/sw/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.o /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.o /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/plot3d.o /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3d-f2pywrappers.o -L/sw/lib/gcc4.8/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0/4.8.1 -lgfortran -o ./libplot3d.so
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/libplot3dmodule.oignoring file /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo/src.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/fortranobject.o

running scons
Removing build directory /var/folders/bv/x7bctfmj1cg0cc79fn073gd80000gn/T/tmpD9L6Fo
```